# Drawing Arrow with sharp end point in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, line

I am going to draw some arrows in my `winform` and I have done most of job.There is only one problem,I can not distinguish among arrows end and start point,they mix in each other and it is not clear that where is start point of each arrow and where is its end point,I have attached an image that shows my problem.I want to know how can I make them sharper or sth like that (a user friendly maybe) arrows that endures can easily see the arrows.
[image]
As you can see because the arrows comes after each other the end and start of them is mixed,How can I fix this problem?
Thank you for your help
here is my code

```
      using (Pen P = new Pen(Color.LightBlue, 3))
            {

                P.StartCap = LineCap.NoAnchor;
                P.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;

                for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
                {
                    int a = (int)result[i] - 65;
                    int b;
                    try
                    {
                        b = (int)result[i + 1] - 65;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        b = (int)result[0] - 65;
                    }

                   Point startPoint = new Point(_guiLocations[a].X, _guiLocations[a].Y);
                   Point endPoint = new Point(_guiLocations[b].X, _guiLocations[b].Y);
                   pnlView.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(P, startPoint, endPoint);

                }


            }
```

Comment: What is "-65" in your code?

Comment: @al_amanat in fact I have two lists,one is a char[] and another is list of points that has x,y these two list is connected to each other with position in list and char[] list is serie of alphabetic from A to Z so in case of finding char position in list I must use -65 .so the position of A is 0 and B is 1..The points works fine but I can not see end point of arrow because of drawings quality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified your code for a little to make it easier, but I guess you can modify it to your purporses:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        var nodes = new[] { new Node { Code = 'A', Position = new Point(10, 10) }, new Node { Code = 'B', Position = new Point(45, 45) } };

        using (Pen P = new Pen(Color.LightBlue, 3))
        {

            P.StartCap = LineCap.NoAnchor;
            P.CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(4, 8, false);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Length; i++)
            {
                var node = nodes[i];
                for (int j = i; j < nodes.Length; j++)
                {
                    var node2 = nodes[j];

                    if (node == node2)
                        continue;

                    Point startPoint = new Point(node.Position.X, node.Position.Y);
                    Point endPoint = new Point(node2.Position.X, node2.Position.Y);
                    pnlView.CreateGraphics().DrawLine(P, startPoint, endPoint);
                }
            }
        }
        pnlView.PerformLayout();
    }
```

I have defined entity-class for a Node as followed:

```
class Node
{
     public char Code { get; set; }
     public Point Position { get; set; }
}
```

And define CustomEndCap instead of EndCap:

```
P.CustomEndCap = new AdjustableArrowCap(4, 8, false);
```